# Query Optimization - subselect in Left Join

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on optimizing a sql query, and I found a particular line that appears to be killing my queries performance:

```
LEFT JOIN anothertable lastweek
AND lastweek.date>= (SELECT MAX(table.date)-7 max_date_lweek 
                                 FROM table table
                                 WHERE table.id= lastweek.id) 
AND lastweek.date< (SELECT MAX(table.date) max_date_lweek 
                                 FROM table table  
                                 WHERE table.id= lastweek.id)
```

I'm working on a way of optimizing these lines, but I'm stumped. If anyone has any ideas, please let me know!

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id   | Operation                         | Name            | Rows      | Bytes      | Cost   | Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                 |   1908654 |  145057704 | 720461 | 00:00:29 |
|  * 1 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                 |   1908654 |  145057704 | 720461 | 00:00:29 |
|    2 |    VIEW                           | VW_DCL_880D8DA3 |    427487 |    7694766 | 716616 | 00:00:28 |
|  * 3 |     HASH JOIN                     |                 |    427487 |   39328804 | 716616 | 00:00:28 |
|    4 |      VIEW                         | VW_SQ_2         |   7174144 |  193701888 | 278845 | 00:00:11 |
|    5 |       HASH GROUP BY               |                 |   7174144 |  294139904 | 278845 | 00:00:11 |
|    6 |        TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL  | TASK            | 170994691 | 7010782331 |  65987 | 00:00:03 |
|  * 7 |      HASH JOIN                    |                 |   8549735 |  555732775 | 429294 | 00:00:17 |
|    8 |       VIEW                        | VW_SQ_1         |   7174144 |  172179456 | 278845 | 00:00:11 |
|    9 |        HASH GROUP BY              |                 |   7174144 |  294139904 | 278845 | 00:00:11 |
|   10 |         TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL | TASK            | 170994691 | 7010782331 |  65987 | 00:00:03 |
|   11 |       TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL   | TASK            | 170994691 | 7010782331 |  65987 | 00:00:03 |
| * 12 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL      | TASK            |   1908654 |  110701932 |   2520 | 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - access("SYS_ID"(+)="TASK"."PARENT")
* 3 - access("ITEM_2"="TASK_LWEEK"."SYS_ID")
* 3 - filter("TASK_LWEEK"."SNAPSHOT_DATE"<"MAX_DATE_LWEEK")
* 7 - access("ITEM_1"="TASK_LWEEK"."SYS_ID")
* 7 - filter("TASK_LWEEK"."SNAPSHOT_DATE">=INTERNAL_FUNCTION("MAX_DATE_LWEEK"))
* 12 - storage("TASK"."CLOSED_AT" IS NULL OR "TASK"."CLOSED_AT">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)-15)
* 12 - filter("TASK"."CLOSED_AT" IS NULL OR "TASK"."CLOSED_AT">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)-15)
```

Comment: I would suggest that you create a small query to demonstrate your problem, and show sample data from all relevant tables.

Comment: did you run an explain plan and post the results

Comment: can you put the whole query and the explain plan ?

Comment: not enough info as posted - maybe use a WITH clause to encapsulate that date logic - also using those nested views is probably not good..

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` doesn't make use of the `ON` keyword. What is `lastweek` being joined on? I'm not sure if the absence of `ON` works or not, you could try adding it and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are not even showing the select. As I can see that the select is done over Exadata ( Table Access Storage Full ) , perhaps you need to ask yourself why do you need to make 4 access to the same table.

You access fourth times ( lines 6, 10, 11, 12 ) to the main table TASK with 170994691 rows ( based on estimation of the CBO ). I don't know whether the statistics are up-to-date or it is optimizing sampling kick in due to lack of good statistics.

A solution could be use WITH for generating intermediate results that you need several times in your outline query

```
with my_set as 
 (SELECT MAX(table.date)-7 max_date_lweek  , 
         max(table.date) as max_date, 
         id from FROM table ) 
select 
.......................
from ...
left join anothertable lastweek on ( ........ ) 
left join myset on ( anothertable.id = myset.id ) 
where 
      lastweek.date >= myset.max_date_lweek  
      and 
      lastweek.date < myset.max_date
```

Please, take in account that you did not provide the query, so I am guessing a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Since complete information is not available I will suggest:

You are using the same query twice then why not use CTE such as

```
with CTE_example as (SELECT MAX(table.date), max_date_lweek, ID 
                                 FROM table table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your explain plan, the only table being accessed is `TASK`.  From that, I infer that the tables in your example: `ANOTHERTABLE` and `TABLE` are actually the same table and that, therefore, you are trying to get the last week of data that exists in that table for each `id` value.

If all that is true, it should be much faster to use an analytic function to get the max date value for each `id` and then limit based on that.

Here is an example of what I mean.  Note I use "dte" instead of "date", to remove confusion with the reserved word "date".

```
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT lastweek.*, 
                   max(dte) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ) max_date 
            FROM   anothertable lastweek ) lastweek
ON 1=1  -- whatever other join conditions you have, seemingly omitted from your post
AND lastweek.dte >= lastweek.max_date - 7;
```

Again, this only works if I am correct in thinking that `table` and `anothertable` are actually the same table.